# register_theme_directory and broken deploys

Tags: themes

I use `register_theme_directory()` in a mu-plugin to register a custom theme directory (located at `project_root/app/views/`, with site_root at `project_root/public/` and WordPress in a Git submodule at `project_root/public/wp/`. `WP_CONTENT_DIR` is at `project_root/public/content`).

I also use Capistrano to deploy my project.

Every time I deploy, the site breaks, and I get this message in my Dashboard:

> ERROR: The themes directory is either empty or doesn’t exist. Please check your installation.

When I navigate into the Appearance tab, my theme doesn't appear on the list until I refresh the page. After refreshing, I can see my theme, activate it, and everything works again.

Why might this be happening on every deploy? I am confused as to why WordPress would think the theme doesn't exist, when it definitely does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a bug in `class-wp-upgrader.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22501): WordPress is using the fixed path `WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes'` and doesn’t use `get_theme_root()`.

I have written [a patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/22501/class-wp-upgrader.get_theme_root.patch) 7 months ago … which was *too late* for WordPress 3.6 – the fix was delayed just today.

So use my patch, or jump in on Trac and explain why this is important.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Too bad there's no fix other than patching core. Hopefully talking it up in Trac will get the issue taken care of. (Incidentally, I had an issue and patch delayed today as well... I think they were bug gardening today.)